# Get information about customer by email id in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

I want to get information of customer by email id, so i create a method in controller with content:

```
public function showAction(){
    $customer_email = "abc@mail.com";
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
    echo $customer->getId();
    echo $customer->getFirstName();
    echo $customer->getEmail(); 
}
```

but when run it return null value, i don't know why?. please help me

Comment: Do you run multiple websites ? If so, are customer accounts shared globally or by website ?

Comment: Not run multiple websites

Comment: Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() always return value 0

Comment: Are you sure that a customer with this email address exists ? What does it give when you comment out the `setWebsiteId()` call ?

Comment: @rocky: Did you try to fetch customer information through another email id ? As i can see there is no error in code except getFirstName() should be getFirstname().

Comment: when i using $customer->setWebsiteId(1), it's return correct email of customer but i using $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()), it's return null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your system configuration, customer accounts are shared by website, so the `loadByEmail` method needs to be used on a customer model that has a value for `website_id`, and this website ID must correspond to the website to which the customer is associated.

Or, as your controller seems to be an admin one, `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()` returns 0, which does not correspond.

So, your solution is either to share customer accounts globally (**System** > **Configuration** > **Customers** > **Customer Configuration** > **Account Sharing Options**), as it won't change much things if you only run a single website, either to use a website ID that has to be specified by an user, or at least not retrieved by `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()`.

Comment: Clearly answer. Thanks you so much