# loadByEmail and load method issue in Magento in Customer Model

Tags: php, magento

i getting error while i am try to use get Entity Id (getEntityId()) Method in customer/customer model object.

Please check my bellow's code.

I want to use bellow's code. But its showing error.

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail('email@example.com'); //load customer by email id
```

While bellow's code is working fine. with getEntityId()

```
$id=3;
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
```

So Please give solution for loadByEmail() method.

Comment: what does get_class($customer) gives ? does your customer exists for the website you're in ? do you really need to set the website (in cron or in backend the website_id is 0) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally i founds solution for my problem.

```
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite('admin')->getId()); 
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
```

Answer (score 16):

The store  website code is wrong,
it should be `Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId()`

Here modified code is

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
 $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
 $customer->loadByEmail('email@example.com')
```

Comment: Thanks bhai :-) I was searching for this.. You solved my problem in single shot.

Answer (score 3):

This is a duplicate of

[Get information about customer by email id in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149256/get-information-about-customer-by-email-id-in-magento)

Your code is correct but the `Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId()` is returning a 0 which does not correspond.

If you, for instance, use the following:

```
$customer->setWebsiteId(1);
```

You'll most likely notice that the customer now loads. The reasoning is because customer accounts are shared by website. You can read the aforementioned post for further info.

Comment: Please add commentary to what you did versus just some code

Comment: working fine. But is there way to make this 1 value dynamic. like if pass website code that in response i will get website id.

Comment: Please have a look at the original question's answer as this covers the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Other posible solution is  a collection:

```
$customerExist = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('email', $email )
            ->getFirstItem();
```